# Codeigniter version(3.0.3)Error in model Undefined property: Admin::$Admin_model

Tags: php, codeigniter

**controller**

```
public function add_package()
    {
       $this->load->model('admin_model');
      $this->Admin_model->add_packages($package);
    }
```

admin_model.php

```
    class Admin_model extends CI_Model
    {
      public function add_packages($data)
        {
            return $this->db->insert('george_packges',$data);
        }
}
```

Why i  will getting this error `Undefined property: Admin::$Admin_model` and also this

> fatal error: Call to a member function add_packages() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\holiday\application\controllers\Admin.php on line 130

Comment: try   $this->admin_model->add_packages($package);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the loading model variable as the model loaded and used was different so the variable was not matching.

<strike>$this->Admin_model->add_packages($package);</strike>//currently used

```
$this->admin_model->add_packages($package);
```